# How to pass context to method in a callback from event handler?

Tags: jquery, this, jquery-callback

I've always written event handlers in jQuery like this:

```
$('.some-class').click(function() {
    alert('bla');
});
```

I learnt that would be better to avoid using anonymous functions in the callback, so I'm trying this way:

```
var function someMethod = function() {
    alert('bla');
};

$('.some-class').click(someMethod);
```

How can I pass a reference to the element I clicked on to `someMethod`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` :

```js
var someMethod = function() {
  console.log(this); // => <button class="some-class">OK</button>
  console.log($(this).text()); // => OK
};

$('.some-class').click(someMethod);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="some-class">OK</button>
```

Comment: ok, this works. Thanks. I was sure I'd tried this and I was getting a reference to the window object